# View not updating (changing ViewModel but not ViewModel type)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I use the classic MVVM pattern where I define DataTemplats as resources and then bind a Content attribute to corresponding ViewModels in a view. The DataTemplates are defined like so:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PersonViewModel}">
        <vw:PersonView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ProductViewModel}">
        <vw:ProductView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

In a view somewhere I use a ContentPresenter and bind the Content attribute

```
<Grid DataContext={Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"}>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding DetailsViewModel}"></ContentPresenter>
</Grid>
```

In my user interface I have a left panel with a list of items, lets say persons and products. To the right I am loading the details for each item. When I click a person I will change the DetailsViewModel property of the MainViewModel like so:

```
DetailsViewModel = new PersonViewModel();
```

And if I click a product I will then ofcourse do:

```
DetailsViewModel = new ProductViewModel();
```

As long as I switch between person and product in the left panel the correct view will load into the ContentPresenter.

But here is the problem. If I click an object of the **same type** (i.e click person A, then click person B) the view will not update to reflect the change in ViewModel. Note that at this point we create a new instance of the PersonViewModel and assign it to DetailsViewModel. Setting the DetailsViewModel will correctly raise an event, but InitializeComponent() in the PersonView's code behind file is never called. What is going on here, and what can I do to solve it?

Comment: What does it mean you click object of the same type? More code reflecting such a situation would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What I mean is, when I click Person A I will set DetailsViewModel = new PersonViewModel("Person A"); and when I click another person I will set DetailsViewModel = new PersonViewModel("Person B"); This is done inside a command which is called when you click the list. The property DetailsViewModel is updated with a new view model instance but the type of the view model didn't change. I would expect my new view model to refresh or recreate the view, but this is not happening. It will simply show the data for Person A.

Comment: @sunefred Did you ever figure out what was causing this?  Seeing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this exact pattern before and it has worked.

Two things:

I assume your `DetailsViewModel` property on the ViewModel is
    raising a `PropertyChanged` event

The data template for my views also has a  `DataContext="{Binding}"` defined.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PersonViewModel}">
  <vw:PersonView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, this is working for you even when you switch from one instance of PersonViewModel to another instance of PersonViewModel?

Comment: I am observing the exact same behaviour. When the the content for my ContentPresenter changes to another instance with the same type then a new view instance is not created. I am still investigating a workaround.

Comment: And yes, I have confirmed that the property that is bound to the ContentPresenter.Content property is raising a property changed event.